# IFrame reloads Parent (entire page)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I've a one page website, which is navigated using one top navbar. Once a link is clicked, the page scrolls to the clicked section.

Now I have one section, which need an iFrame(external) but this iFrame always reloads the entire page if a link is clicked, making it unable to use the iFrame efficiently (also an self hosted iFrame does this).

Now my question is: Is it possible to not refresh the entire page, if a link is clicked in the iFrame?
I just want the iFrame to navigate to that link, without reloading the entire page.

The problem I'm facing is, that after a link click, the page is reloaded and thus scrolled to the top of the page, while the iFrame is on 3/5 of the page.
Code of the head:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Site Title</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="css/animate.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!--CSS -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="color/default.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Code of the section:

```
<section id="occasions" class="home-section text-center bg-gray">

    <div class="heading-about">
        <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2">
                <div class="wow bounceInDown" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <div class="section-heading">
                <h2>Header H2</h2>
                <h5>Header H5</h5>
                <i class="fa fa-2x fa-angle-down"></i>

                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-lg-offset-5">
            <hr class="marginbot-50">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="wow fadeInLeft" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                <div class="occasionframe">
                    <iframe id="voorraadFrame" class="embed-responsive-item" style="width: 100%; margin-right:-10px;" frameborder="0" onload="scroll(0,0);" src="http://www.voorraadmodule.nl/86c0/"></iframe>
                </div>
    </div>      
    </div>

    <div class="page-scroll">
        <a href="#service" class="btn btn-circleblue">
            <i class="fa fa-angle-double-down animated"></i>
        </a>
    </div>
</section>
```

and the javascript libs:

```
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/jquery.scrollTo.js"></script>
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
```

custom.js:

```
(function ($) {

new WOW().init();

jQuery(window).load(function() { 
    jQuery("#preloader").delay(100).fadeOut("slow");
    jQuery("#load").delay(100).fadeOut("slow");
});


//jQuery to collapse the navbar on scroll
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".navbar").offset().top > 60) {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("top-nav-collapse");
        $(".active").focusout();
    } else {
        $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("top-nav-collapse");
    }
});

//jQuery for page scrolling feature - requires jQuery Easing plugin
$(function() {
    $('.navbar-nav li a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
    $('.page-scroll a').bind('click', function(event) {
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1500, 'easeInOutExpo');
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});

})(jQuery);
```

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:** onload="scroll(0,0);" was the problem...

Comment: Sounds like the links on the iFrame have their `target=""` set to parent. Check the links to see if they are or check of there is a `<base target="_parent" />` in the head of the iFrame'd page.

Comment: Well, if I create a custom html and put this as src it also reloads the entire page. Also I searched for _parent target but couldn't find this...

Comment: The behavior you want is the default behavior. There must be something else added which is causing it not to work. Code sample or jsfiddle would be helpful.

Comment: Try setting the links, if you can, in the iFrame to `target="_self"` which will tell the browser to load the link inside the iFrame.

Comment: I tried target="_self", but this doesn't work. I don't think it's something from the iFrame, because every iFrame does this.